# How to call destroy with parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I am looking for a way to pass parameters to destroy to log which user is responsible for the record's destruction.

Each model I use has a corresponding history table where I log each time the record is saved, all parameters on the record, and which user called for it to be saved. I want to make sure that I do the same when destroying a record.

For save, I just overrode the `save` method with `save(user_id, source)` since I don't use any `before_save` callbacks. With destroy, I want to preserve the callbacks (`has_many :submodel, dependent: destroy`) while still enforcing logging.

Ideally I can have something like the following:

```
def destroy(user_id, source)
    self.transaction do
        #destroy all associations, using same user_id and source
        self.log_descruction(user_id, source)
        #destroy self
    end
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Due to the way `ActiveRecord::Base` is constructed (e.g. including modules to build functionality) you should be able to call `super` to call the original version of `destroy`. This should retain all the hooks; however I have never actually tried it

Comment: @engineersmnky that makes sense. Do you know how I could then pass the same parameters to the submodels I want to destroy via the callback?

Comment: I can't say I have ever tried but have you considered using a library that already supports this functionality like [`audited`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) or [`papertrail`](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail)

Comment: I've used papertrail quite often, it's very good, does exactly what (I think) you want.

Comment: I had no idea such a gem existed, but it looks just about perfect.

Comment: @engineersmnky I am having issues with calling `super.destroy` inside my transaction. I am getting an argument error which says that I'm passing two args to destroy, but it accepts zero. The stack trace seems to think that I'm calling transaction.destroy()

Comment: @C.J.Coffey it would just be `super()` not `super.destroy`. Use the explicit parentheses becuase it is trying to pass the current arguments `user_id` and  `source` but you can't pass any to `destroy`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to preserve `before_save`. Can't you use `before_destroy` call back

See: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#destroying-an-object

you just need to call a method before_destroy the resource. And in that method save the log.

Comment: Do you know if that works like a transaction? I would like to ensure that the history and the deletion are both completed, hence my reasoning to override destroy. I also don't see how I can pass parameters with this method